# Node.js/Mongo schema validation error regardless of POST data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-ec2

I have mongo and node playing together on AWS EC2. Node (w/ Express) can connect to Mongo so to start with I've setup a schema with two required fields "sesh" and "location".

This is the javascript that gets called for the post query:

```
app.post('/spotters', function(req,res){

  var newSesh = new modelentry(req.body);

  newSesh.save(function(err){
     if(err)
     res.send(err);

     res.json(req.body);
  });
});
```

modelentry is the schema of course.

I'm trying to POST the following raw/json data using Postman

```
{
 sesh: 1,
 location: [1,2]
}
```

However I always recieve a validation failed message, as follows:

```
    {
  "message": "hotuser validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "errors": {
    "location": {
      "message": "Path `location` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "location"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "location"
    },
    "sesh": {
      "message": "Path `sesh` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "sesh"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "sesh"
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked at a lot of example code and tried tinkering with the functions in app.post but I'm not making any progress. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using the body parser?

Comment: Yes body-parser is required before the app.post snippet.